# asp:label doesn't render children

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, web-controls

I have an `asp:label` with a nested custom control and it simply doesn't render. I tried to register a custom `WebControlAdapter` for `Label` type and while debugging I noticed that there is apparently no control in the `Controls` collection, it seems to be completely ignoring any nested elements.

Here's markup

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl13" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txt13" Text="<%$ Resources:Resources, lbl13 %>">
    <asp:ValidationMessage ID="vm13" runat="server" MessageFor="txt13" CssClass="field-validation-error"></asp:ValidationMessage>
</asp:Label>
```

Any idea how to bypass this problem?

Comment: Move `asp:ValidationMessage` out side of `asp:Label` control.

Comment: what if I want it really nested in the label tag.

Comment: Does `ValidationMessage` control work outside of `Label` control? What is the reason behind placing a control inside `Label` control?

Comment: @Win it does work indeed. I just want the validation message span to be in the same label tag.

Comment: Where did you get `asp:ValidationMessage` control? Is it a custom server control?

Comment: I place `TextBox, Button, RequiredFieldValidator` inside Label control; they all display correctly. I think it has something to do with that `ValidationMessage` control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set the `Text` property, it clears the child controls. If you remove the `Text="<%$ Resources:Resources, lbl13 %>"` from the `Label`, your child controls should render.

---

**EDIT**
If you set the `Text` property to a static string and add only literal content, the label will only render the literal content:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Hello"> World</asp:Label>
Output: World
```

If you set the `Text` property to a static string and add child controls, the label will render the text and the child controls:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Hello">
   <asp:Label runat="server" Text="World" />
</asp:Label>
Output: HelloWorld
```

If you set the `Text` property using an expression builder, the label will only render the text:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resources,Hello %>">
   <asp:Label runat="server" Text="World" />
</asp:Label>
Output: Localised version of "Hello"
```

---

To override this behaviour, you'll need a custom `Label` control. For example:

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
   public override string Text
   {
      get { return base.Text; }
      set
      {
         if (HasControls())
         {
            Controls.AddAt(0, new LiteralControl(value));
         }
         else
         {
            base.Text = value;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It is not true. Text will render before controls.

Comment: @Win: It is true. The setter on the `Label`s `Text` property starts with: `if (HasControls()) Controls.Clear()`

Comment: @Win: It only works if you set the text *before* you add the controls.

Comment: really good catch. Is there any way of overriding this behavior, without replacing all those Text attributes with nested literal

Comment: @Burnzy, well, you can always create a custom control if the existing one doesn't suit your needs ;)

Comment: @walther, sure thing, just wanted to make sure there's no way around that hassle of refactoring.

Comment: @Burnzy: You might be able to get away with using the [tagMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) configuration element, but that will map all `Label` elements to your custom `Label` control.

Comment: @RichardDeeming that's totally fine with me, that's probably what i will do, thanks for advises.