# Create checkbox next to each label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need this page to be very easily maintained, so I need most of the stuff to be programmatically generated. I need to create checkboxes next to normal Labels, without touching the .aspx file. right now I generate a list with all labels on my page called `labels`. Each label on my site has an ID beginning with `lbl_`, but the ones that are supposed to have a checkbox begin with `lblx_`. I then want to use something like this to create said checkboxes:

```
foreach (Label label in labels)
{
    if (label.ID.Contains("lblx_"))
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.ID = "cb_statistikname_" + label.ID;

        label.Controls.AddAt(0, cb);
    }
}
```

Right now this code replaces the labels, the same happens when I use `label.Control.Add(cb)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Page.Controls.AddAt()` with combination of `page.Page.Controls.IndexOf()`

```
if(label.Parent != null && label.Parent.Controls.IndexOf(label) >= 0)
    label.Parent.Controls.AddAt(label.Parent.Controls.IndexOf(label) + 1, cb);
```

Note :This should be done in Page PreInit events.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Text property in your Label control, basically all child controls get wiped out. See this answer: [asp:label doesn't render children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988845/asplabel-doesnt-render-children)